# Get order id and price without tax and shipping in Prestashop payment return

Tags: javascript, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

please how can i get order id and price without tax and shipping in themes/mytheme/modules/bankwire/views/templates/hook/payment_return.tpl
to this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="xxxxxxxxxxx" src="https://login.dognet.sk/scripts/fj27g82d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
PostAffTracker.setAccountId('xxxxxxxx');
var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale();
sale.setTotalCost( ***** ); //fill price without tax and shipping
sale.setOrderID( ***** ); //fill ID order

PostAffTracker.register();
</script>
```

sale.setTotalCost({$price_without_tax_and_shpping}); <-- this does not work

Prestashop 1.6.1.13
Is it for affiliate program.

thx for help.

so problem is here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cUvt.png)

code from root/modules/bankwire/bankwire.php

```
public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
    {
        if (!$this->active)
            return;

        $state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();
        if (in_array($state, array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_BANKWIRE'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'))))
        {
            $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
                'bankwireDetails' => Tools::nl2br($this->details),
                'bankwireAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
                'bankwireOwner' => $this->owner,
                'status' => 'ok',
                'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id,
                'price_without_tax_and_shipping' => Tools::displayPrice($params['objOrder']->getTotalProductsWithoutTaxes(), $params['currencyObj'], false)
            ));
            if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
                $this->smarty->assign('reference', $params['objOrder']->reference);
        }
        else
            $this->smarty->assign('status', 'failed');
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment_return.tpl');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short way, edit the module:

```
public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    $state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();
    if (in_array($state, array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_BANKWIRE'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'))))
    {
        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'bankwireDetails' => Tools::nl2br($this->details),
            'bankwireAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
            'bankwireOwner' => $this->owner,
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id,
            'price_without_tax_and_shipping' => Tools::displayPrice($params['objOrder']->getTotalProductsWithoutTaxes(), $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'affiliate_price' => $params['objOrder']->getTotalProductsWithoutTaxes() // You have to add this
        ));
        if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
            $this->smarty->assign('reference', $params['objOrder']->reference);
    }
    else
        $this->smarty->assign('status', 'failed');
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment_return.tpl');
}
```

Then, try to adapt your script with smarty `{literal}` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="xxxxxxxxxxx" src="https://login.dognet.sk/scripts/fj27g82d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    PostAffTracker.setAccountId('xxxxxxxx');
    var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale();
    sale.setTotalCost({/literal}{$affiliate_price}{literal}); //fill price without tax and shipping
    sale.setOrderID({/literal}{$id_order}{literal}); //fill ID order

    PostAffTracker.register();
</script>
{/literal}
```

It should works at 99.99%

Comment: awesome , it works , and please do you have a solution for cashondelivery module?

Comment: Apply the same logic to that module :), it's very similar to bankwire

Comment: I understand, but how the part of hookPaymentReturn will look like ?

Comment: @DominikDravecký Please make another question ;)

Comment: Great ;). I'm glad to hear that ;)